# jQuery conceptual question - sliding in new content

Tags: jquery, ajax, jquery-animate, slide

I am new to jquery and AJAX. I am trying to get my concept down. I will simplify the question as much as possible.

I have a page with some #data pulled from a database, and a next button. When the next button is pressed, I want to refresh the #data with new random data from the database, and so-on. I want this new #data to slide in from the right. I do not want to refresh the whole page, I want the #data to refresh using AJAX.

I got most of this working except the sliding part. I'm not sure conceptually how to handle this. Many examples I've seen have static data on the page, and that data is hidden from view using CSS, and then jquery slides the panel into view using .animate.

In my case, the data isn't on the page, I am loading it with the load function.

My biggest question is where do I load the new data? I can't load it into the existing #data div, because then there would be no slider. Do I make an empty div as a placeholder for the load, then load the new data in there and slide it?

Any assistance would be helpful.

Thank you

Comment: this seems to be exactly what you want, unfortunately its not a free code, but it might be worth the price: http://codecanyon.net/item/jquery-ajax-slide-content/179130?ref=davidvandiepen

Answer (score 0):

Depends on what you mean by "slide in" but something like an accordion slider basically works by having a div you put the data into, and then animate.  If you really want it to come in from another area of the page, you'll put it into a div and use the animation functions to move it.

Just a second, there are some examples of this in sample code, I'll find a link.

Okay, [the docs for .animate()](http://api.jquery.com/animate/) have several examples, so that's a place to start.  Basically, you have a div and you use the `.animate()` method to periodically update the CSS -- which of course includes things like placement on the page.

Here's a nice [photo slider](http://css-tricks.com/revealing-photo-slider/) which is similar in concept.  Again, all you're really doing is changing the CSS, thereby causing the browser to render an element in a different place.

And there are a *bunch* of useful tutorials and examples [here](http://webdesignledger.com/tutorials/13-excellent-jquery-animation-techniques), [here](http://vandelaydesign.com/blog/web-development/jquery-animation-tutorials/), [here](http://sixrevisions.com/javascript/10-awesome-techniques-and-examples-of-animation-with-jquery/), and [here](http://slodive.com/freebies/jquery-animate/).

Comment: I mean slide in from off page. Not an accordion. 

Also, I only have one content area on the page at any given time, so I only have one content div on my page. I suppose I could have another hidden content area, but the first time the page is requested, what would go in there? Would it is totally empty with no markup? As I said, most examples have all of the data already on the page, but in my case, this is new data loading in via AJAX.

Comment: You can have as many divs as you need.  In this case, if you want to have content slide in from off the page, it has to go into *some* element, and the obvious one is a div.  This tutorial might also give you some help: http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/javascript-ajax/inettuts/

Comment: Thanks I'll check out the tuts.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to stick with the examples you mention in your question then what you can do is in your success function insert the data into your html however you need it to be formatted.  This could be in a div or table or whatever.  Make this html "display: none" to start off with.  That way it doesn't show up to the user right away but it still lives in the DOM.  At this point you can think of the html as being in the same "state" your examples are in right before they call animate (think of it as static content at this point).  So the only thing left to do would be to call animate.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Success function of what?

Comment: success function of the ajax call